Can I create a cmake "pseudo target" that will do compile/link options for me?
In my project, I have a mix of dependencies, some with cmake files that I can nicely use target_link_libraries() (e.g. boost_program_options) with, but some don't (e.g. openssl; I have to compile a custom version for compatibility reasons) and I have to use ExternalProject_Add and for them, and then I need to use a mixture of target_link_libraries(), target_compile_options() and target_link_options(), e.g.:
# This is only for certain libraries.
target_compile_options(my_program
  PUBLIC
  -I${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}/include
)

# This is only for certain libraries.
target_link_options(my_program
  PUBLIC
  -L${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}/lib
)

# This is only for everything, but I have to remember
# whether I add the target name or the actual library
# files.
target_link_libraries(my_program
  PUBLIC
  boost_program_options
  libssl.a libcrypto.a
)

What I'd rather do is replace this with something like:
# Everything in one place.
target_link_libraries(my_program
  PUBLIC
  boost_program_options
  openssl_pseudo_target
)

And elsewhere have openssl_pseudo_target tell cmake the appropriate compile/link options/libraries to use.
Is there any way to do this, or achieve a similar effect?

What is problem in using INTERFACE or IMPORTED library target for that?

This is what Interface Libraries are for. They also provide an example similar to what you want to do:

Another use-case is to employ an entirely target-focussed design for usage requirements:
add_library(pic_on INTERFACE)
set_property(TARGET pic_on PROPERTY INTERFACE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
add_library(pic_off INTERFACE)
set_property(TARGET pic_off PROPERTY INTERFACE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE OFF)

add_library(enable_rtti INTERFACE)
target_compile_options(enable_rtti INTERFACE
  $<$<OR:$<COMPILER_ID:GNU>,$<COMPILER_ID:Clang>>:-rtti>
)

add_executable(exe1 exe1.cpp)
target_link_libraries(exe1 pic_on enable_rtti)

This way, the build specification of exe1 is expressed entirely as linked targets, and the complexity of compiler-specific flags is encapsulated in an INTERFACE library target.

P.S. There is also find_package(OpenSSL) which provides needed targets so you don't need to make your own.
